# Select/Deselect All checkbox for checkboxes in next block element

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to deselect/select everything in the following dd.options based "dept_checkbox" being selected for each. Theres around 1 to 100+ checkboxes in each dd block( I put 2 courses in the first "dept_checkbox" section, and 1 in the next) for this snippet.

```
<div class="accordion">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll($(this).parent().next(".options") )"><a href="">EYES|VISI</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_XXX">XXX
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_YYY">YYY
    </label>
  </li>
  </dd>

  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll($(this).parent().next(".options") )"><a href="">EARS|HEAR</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EARS|HEAR" value="course_EEE">EEE
    </label>
  </li>
  </dd>      
</div>
```

I got the following so far far but I'm not sure how to go about it, I'm trying to accomplish this with jquery.

```
  function selectAll(pID ){
    $('.'+pID).find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        *SELECT ALL CHECKBOXES IN OPTIONS SECTION FOR THIS PARENT*
    });     
  }
```

I'm trying to stay away from calling any of the 'name' or 'value' values since they all change. Only things stay static(they will appear with all results) are 'dept_checkbox' for each of the Select all checkboxes and 'options' class which would hold the checkboxes for the previous select/deselect all button to work with.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: a function to make A checkbox that can deselect/select all elements inside the next block element. can be used by any "dept_checkbox" to complete that

Comment: SelectAll(){
 /*  SELECT ALL CHECKBOXES INSIDE THE FOLLOWING block called options */
}

<dt><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll()">X</dt>
<dd class="options">
<label><CHECKBOX></label>
<label><CHECKBOX></label>
<label><CHECKBOX></label>
</dd>

basically it would make all those "'CHECKBOX's" selected/deselected inside the following element of the parent that executed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.dept_checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">EYES|VISI</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_XXX">XXX
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_YYY">YYY
    </label>
    </li>
  </dd>

  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">EARS|HEAR</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EARS|HEAR" value="course_EEE">EEE
    </label>
    </li>
  </dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$('.options').find(':checkbox ').prop({checked: true})`
This finds every checkbox in options, and sets the ':checked' property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```js
checkCheckboxes = function(check){
$(".accordion input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',check);
}

//Uncheck all the checkboxes
checkCheckboxes(false);
//Check all the checkboxes
checkCheckboxes(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll($(this).parent().next(".options") )"><a href="">EYES|VISI</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_XXX">XXX
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EYES|VISI" value="course_YYY">YYY
    </label>
  </li>
  </dd>

  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll($(this).parent().next(".options") )"><a href="">EARS|HEAR</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="course_EARS|HEAR" value="course_EEE">EEE
    </label>
  </li>
  </dd>      
</div>
```